# AS2: Input text to integer?

Tags: flash, dynamic, actionscript, textbox, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make an app in Flash Actionscript 2 that includes multiplying an input text by eight. There are six text boxes; half are input and half are dynamic. When the user inputs a number into one, the output in the corresponding one should change to eight times the original amount. (However, the middle text box and its corresponding text box stay equal to each other.)

I don't want the user to have to press a button all the time, so outside the frame I put a "control panel" movieclip. It basically has two frames, one with the tasks I want, so it basically performs them 12 times per second at 24 fps.

Now, the middle text boxes, which are equal, work fine. I can change the first middle one to 6, and the second will be six. Same thing with any other number. But the other two sets of text boxes, the ones that get multiplied by 8, they always come up as NaN.

I give all of the input text boxes a value of 0 when the app is started. Strangely, the dynamic ones were also 0. I tried making the input text boxes start at 2, and sure enough, the dynamic ones were 16. However, they became NaN the second I touched the inputs. Obviously, this means the problem is with the string from the inputs.

I tried tracing the string from one of the inputs before I convert it into an integer. I inputted a 3, and when I traced it, instead of getting "3" like I had expected, I got this:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="18" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">3</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

So that's obviously the problem; I just don't know how to fix it so the output is just "3" or whatever the number is.

Here are the variables:

```
• NTO_x = input that will be multiplied by 8 
• NTO_y = input that will not be changed 
• NTO_z = input that will be multiplied by 8 
• OFN_x = output of NTO_x 
• OFN_y = output of NTO_y 
• OFN_z = output of NTO_z
```

And here's the code:

*On the frame of the scene:*

```
//Sets the textboxes to number-only
NTO_x.restrict = "0-9";
NTO_x = "0"
NTO_y.restrict = "0-9";
NTO_y = "0";
NTO_z.restrict = "0-9";
NTO_z = "0";`
```

*On the second frame of the "control panel" movieclip:*

```
//Multiplies x and z by 8
_root.OFN_x = Number(_root.NTO_x) * 8;
_root.OFN_y = _root.NTO_y;
_root.OFN_z = Number(_root.NTO_z) * 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

InputTextbox (Is an input box with the variable of InputTextbox)

TimesEight = _root.InputTextbox * 8;

name the dynamic text box "TimesEight" in the variable

I can attach an example but if you cant figure out something like this I would do much more research....

Comment: You must not have read the whole thing. I already said that the string for InputTextbox (in your example) isn't just what I type in. It also gives me a load of text format tags. I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that the string is just the actual text in the box.

Comment: Well, someone found me a great function to remove those tags. Here it is for anyone in the future who has this issue: http://snipplr.com/view/28329/